# How do I get Lucida fonts?

Tags: fonts

It used to be that you installed `sun-java6-fonts`, but that package is gone.

What do you install now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just get it from Java.

- Download the latest version from [Java.com](http://java.com)
- Extract it:

  ```
  sh jre-6u30-linux-x64.bin
  ```
- Find the fonts. In my case they're just sitting in `jre1.6.0_30/lib/fonts`
- Install them. You can just double click each font and click install font. Or you could copy them into your local `.fonts` directory like so:

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/.fonts
  cp jre1.6.0_30/lib/fonts/*.ttf ~/.fonts/
  ```

Comment: The fonts are now in `jre1.7.0_21/lib/fonts`. I downloaded the "Linux" option from http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?locale=en

Comment: Yeah the exact location *is* going to change if you use a different version of the JRE.

Comment: Weird: there's just no «Lucida Blackletter». I wanted to set it for a variable types in Emacs, in to my wonder discovered that this font is only in my home Kubuntu. In a job Kubuntu no such… I found this question, so I was wondered that it isn't a defaul font of Kubuntu. And alas: the `<jre root dir>/lib/fonts/`  have no such a font.

Answer (score 3):

Go to [Lucida font](http://fontseek.com/fonts/lucida.htm#free_lucida). They have a section of free Lucida fonts to download.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems none of the links works.

Comment: Sorry, can't do a downvote cuz of reputation. None of the fonts in the link is free.

Comment: Following links you will land on http://www.themeworld.com/fonts/indexL9.html where there is link to http://www.themeworld.com/cgi-bin/redir.pl/fonts/lucida.zip

Comment: @Hi-Angel maybe they were free in 2012 though...